# Should you catch all exceptions in your main method

Tags: java, exception

Is it correct to catch everything into the main? If not, why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // A lot
        // of
        // calls
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Comment: That's a way. What do you really need?

Comment: You aren't catching everything there - catch Throwable if you want to do that. But in this example, why bother? You're just printing the exception and the the program finishes ( as it is the last statement ). If you didnt catch it, and just made main throw Exception, it'd have the same effect

Comment: If you're really worried, you can use [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to trap exceptions

Comment: I'd only catch if you intend to do something useful. After all, somebody might want to call your main() programmatically and then you're going to swallow any exceptions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's better to separate out the catches IMO, so that you can handle each separately even if you end up handling these the same. It's also easier to see what the risks are, what the *catch* is, when you come back to your code. Just a quick example:

```
try {

} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    request.abort();
} finally {
    client.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you do is call `e.printStacktrace ()`, I do not think it is worthwhile. The JVM will do something like that anyway. But I believe it is worthwhile if you output a meaningful message; stacktraces are meaningful only to programmers.

Answer (score 0):

It will catch every `Exception` from the `try{}` block, It might not catch if there is another catch catching in the inner code

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you only need to show some error messages when an exception arise, I guess it's ok. But if you find the need to make some kind of processing depending on the type of exception, then you'll be better off try-catching in the inner code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it makes no sense since you do not process the exception you catch but simply print it. If you declare `main throws checked_exceptions_your_code_throws_list` you will get the same result (JVM will print exception) and a cleaner code. And if your code throws no checked exception then do not declare any exceptions at all.